# How to do vertical carousel news slider using JQuery and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a vertical slider using jQuery and CSS. Here is my code:

**HTML & JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector = '.slideshow';
</script>
<div class="slideshow vertical" data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=0 data-cycle-next="#next3" data-cycle-prev="#prev3" data-cycle-carousel-visible=2 data-cycle-carousel-vertical=true>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>
<div class="center">
    <button id="prev3">∧ Prev</button>
    <button id="next3">∨ Next</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slideshow {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}
.slideshow img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
}
div.responsive img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto
}
.cycle-pager {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 5px
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natnaydenova/7uXPx/)

However, it's showing only two images. I want to show 3 or four images.

I also have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/eNZrQW), but it's showing only one slider text.
How can I change and make it 2 to 3?

Comment: https://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/eNZrQW another link is http://jsfiddle.net/kc723a4u/

Comment: Fixed your post, man. Try to learn how to format code correctly and ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height of `.slideshow` to `312px` this should do the job.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7uXPx/228/).

Or even easier, set the `data-cycle-carousel-visible=X` to the desired amount X of pictures shown. For example `data-cycle-carousel-visible=3`

Comment: why it's not moving automatically?

Comment: because `data-cycle-timeout` is set to zero. Put in a number for the desired speed (larger number means the images stay longer before they change). Something like `data-cycle-timeout=1000`